# Node js express static not receiving post response on the client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, post

Hi guys i'm from mobile development and trying to know more about the node js runtime, so i've already a simple "app" js client-side and i'am trying to use it with the node js express server.

For my purpose i've used a static file because all my html it's generated by js with DOM.

**The problem:**

**When i'm doing a post with ajax to store values in the DB it's always redirects me to the index.html and do not execute my client-side callback code to create the table.**

app.js

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let favicon = require('serve-favicon');
let logger = require('morgan');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let index = require('./routes/index');
let cups = require('./routes/route-cup');
let leagues = require('./routes/route-league');
let players = require('./routes/route-player');
let teams = require('./routes/route-team');

let app = express();

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', '/images/favicon.png')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cookieParser());


app.use('/cups', cups);
app.use('/leagues', leagues);
app.use('/players', players);
app.use('/teams', teams);
app.use(express.static("public", {
    "index": "index.html"
}));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

route:

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();
let mysql = require("mysql");
let executeSql = require("../scripts/execute-sql");

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    executeSql.executeSelect(res, function (rows, fields) {
        res.json(rows);
    }, "SELECT * FROM `footTour-sgbd`.player;")
});

router.post('/submit-player', function (req, res, next) {
    let obj = req.body;
    let keys = Object.keys(obj);
    let placeHolders = new Array(keys.length).fill("?");
    let values = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
    let sql = "INSERT INTO `footTour-sgbd`.`player` (" + keys.toString() + ") VALUES (" + placeHolders.toString() + ")";

    sql = mysql.format(sql, values);
    executeSql.executeSelect(res, function (rows, fields) {
        // res.json(rows);
        res.end('{"success" : "Updated Successfully", "status" : 200}');

    }, sql);
});

module.exports = router;
```

js client-side request:

```
 let formPlayer = createForm(formName, formName);
    formPlayer.addEventListener("submit", function (response) {

        let playerName = document.getElementById("name").value;
        let playerHeight = document.getElementById("height").value;
        let playerBirthdate = document.getElementById("birthDate").value;
        let playerCountry = document.getElementById("countryEnum").value;
        let playerPosition = document.getElementById("positionTypeEnum").value;

        // let player = formToJson(formPlayer);
        let player = new Player(playerName, playerBirthdate, playerCountry, playerHeight, playerPosition)
        insertPlayer(
            function (response) {
                createPlayersTable();

            }, function (status, response) {

                showSnackBar(`Error creating player (${status})`, 3000);
                createPlayersTable();
            }, player);
    });

function insertPlayer(onSuccess, onError, data) {

    ajaxHelper("/players/submit-player", onSuccess, onError, "POST", data);
}

function ajaxHelper(url, onSuccess, onError, verb, data) {
    verb = verb || "GET";
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(verb, url);
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            onSuccess && onSuccess(xhr.response);
        } else {
            onError && onError(this.status, xhr.response);
        }
    });
    if (data) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    } else {
        xhr.send();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add preventDefault() in a form EventListener:

```
formPlayer.addEventListener("submit", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); //<-- THIS

    let playerName = document.getElementById("name").value;
    let playerHeight = document.getElementById("height").value;
    let playerBirthdate = document.getElementById("birthDate").value;
    let playerCountry = document.getElementById("countryEnum").value;
    let playerPosition = document.getElementById("positionTypeEnum").value;

    // let player = formToJson(formPlayer);
    let player = new Player(playerName, playerBirthdate, playerCountry, playerHeight, playerPosition)
    insertPlayer(
        function (response) {
            createPlayersTable();

        }, function (status, response) {

            showSnackBar(`Error creating player (${status})`, 3000);
            createPlayersTable();
        }, player);
});
```

Comment: thank you very much i'm owning a cup of coffee if you ever came to Lisbon send me a pm here and i will pay my debt ;)

Comment: ahahah ok..!! :D